# octave error undefined near line 1 column 1

Tags: file, matrix, octave, numerical-methods

I try to read a matrix from a file.  The code is very simple

```
function [mat] = read(file)

mat = load(file_points)
```

But when I try to run it

```
read('file')
```

mat =

scalar structure containing the fields:

```
mat =


   3  4  6
   3  5  1
```

it shows the matrix, 
but when I run this command...

```
>>mat(1,1)
```

> error: 'points' undefined near line 1 column 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55224023/octave-fscanf-problems.

Comment: `points=read_input_data('cls/cluster_1.points')`. Also add a semicolon at the end of your statements if you don’t what Octave to display the resulting matrices.

Comment: Your function declaration is read but you call read_input_data, please fix this error

Comment: "I think that are comments, so it shouldn't influence too much". Actually, those comments in the header are what *make* this text file a .mat file that you can read with `load`. Try removing them and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Octave Forge about `load()`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/load.html)

> If invoked with a single output argument, Octave returns data instead of inserting variables in the symbol table. If the data file contains only numbers (TAB- or space-delimited columns), a matrix of values is returned. *Otherwise, load returns a **structure** with members corresponding to the names of the variables in the file.*

According to above, variable points is a (scalar) structure.
However, if you use `the_matrix_you_want = points.points;` you would retrieve matrix.