# Read a matrix from a file which contains a header

Tags: octave

I have a file which contains a header(specific to a file used by octave) and I have to read the matrix contained in the file. The idea is that I have a function and the file location is stored in a string let's say location. If I try to do load(location) I get some parse error and that matrix will not be load.

```
    function [extract] = read(location)
    matrix = ?;
    end
```

Comment: This is the third same question this week, even with the same function stub so Im sure this is some homework. Use the search function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [octave error undefined near line 1 column 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229467/octave-error-undefined-near-line-1-column-1)